# google-cloud/resource' cloud function not listing all projects in response

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using a cloud function written in node.js to list projects this is the index.js file containing the method, When I trigger this function I am getting only 1 project printed. ProjectA -> the cloud function also resides in ProjectA, I have another ProjectB which is not getting printed which is also in ACTIVE mode. I have owner permission for both the projects.

```
const {Resource} = require('@google-cloud/resource');
const resource = new Resource();

async function getProjects() {

    try {
        // Lists all current projects
        const [projects] = await resource.getProjects();
        
        console.log(`success in getProjects() call`);

        // Set a uniform endTime for all the resulting messages
        const endTime = new Date();
        const endTimeStr = endTime.toISOString();

        // sample 2019-11-12T17:58:26.068483Z

        for (var i=0; i<projects.length;i++) {
            console.log("Total Projects ",projects.length) //Printing as 1 instead of correct 2
            // Only publish messages for active projects
            if (projects[i]["metadata"]["lifecycleState"] === config.ACTIVE)  {   
                // Construct a Pub/Sub message 
                console.log(`About to send Pub/Sub message ${projects[i]}}`);
                const pubsubMessage = {
                        "token": config.METRIC_EXPORT_PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN,
                        "project_id": projects[i]["id"],
                        "end_time": endTimeStr
                }
           } 

    }
} catch(err) {
    console.error("Error in getProjects()");
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
}
```

}

However if i try the google api link
`https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#try-it`
I am getting 2 projects as response which i have access to.

Comment: With the correct authentication information, your code works! Use a custom service account on Cloud Function and grant it on the 2 projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using custom service account and after I added roles/viewer it is listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a Cloud Function you choose a service account that will execute it, normally it's the "App Engine default service account (`project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`), that service account should have the "Project Owner" role.

The API call from the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#try-it) uses an API key that it's tied to your user account no the service account used to execute the Cloud Functions, that's why it shows you all your projects.

To fix your issue just add the service account, that you're using to execute the Cloud Function, to all your Projects with the `Project Owner` role, although other roles (like `Project Viewer`) are enough to list it.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, I did not find any particular project viewer role for the service account so I added this role roles/viewer to that service account and now the cloud function is listing 2 projects, is this role ok roles/viewer?

Comment: Try to add the service account inside IAM -> Click on ADD -> And Select Project then click on Viewer on the New Members just paste the service account used to execute the Cloud Function. However, as already said, there should other roles that may suffice the requirement